# A word that sums up “taken out of context”

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word that sums up or is similar to something being “so taken out of context”

E.g. a person is responding to something someone else said but completely twists what the first person said to fit their own narrative and agenda. I know it’s something I’ve heard before, I’m just drawing a blank.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate, so here are some. https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/taken_out_of_context.html

Comment: What is wrong with the word you used — *twisted*? *That is so twisted* or *That has been so twisted.*

Comment: Is the 'so' in "so taken out of context" intentional?

Comment: @HippoSawrUs please use the answer box for answers instead of comments.  What duplicate do you mean with that link?

Answer (score 1):

**Contextomy** [[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/contextomy)]:

> 1. the practice of misquoting someone by shortening the quotation or by leaving out surrounding words or sentences that would place the quotation in context.
> 2. an instance of this.

See also [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoting_out_of_context) (my emphases):

> Quoting out of context (sometimes referred to as **contextomy** or **quote mining**) is an informal fallacy in which a passage is removed from its surrounding matter *in such a way as to distort its intended meaning*.

Answer (score 0):

According to Cambridge dictionary **Equivocation** is

> a way of speaking that is intentionally not clear and is confusing to
> other people, especially to hide the truth, or something said in this
> way

Examples:

- He answered openly and honestly without hesitation or equivocation.
- After a year of equivocation, he granted me access to his papers.

Synonym : **verbiage**, e.g. *The commission wants less verbiage and more concrete action*.

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking for the word **decontextualized,** [defined by Cambridge as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/decontextualized)

> shown or considered without a context